# How can I repeat code through entire data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a few lines of code that work like I want them too but I don't know how to repeat it through all rows of my data.
This probably seems like a rather simple thing but since I started VBA just a few days ago I struggle with this line of code

If I continue with `ActiveCell.Offset(-1,-4)` after my code it's a bug and I don't know how to repeat the code through all rows.

```
Sub SelectRowsWithNoBlanks()
    Range("A2").Select
    
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value <> "" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) <> "" And ActiveCell(0, 1) <> "" And ActiveCell(0, 1) <> "" Then
        Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 4)).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) • Completely avoid `Select` and `ActiveCell` and your live will be **a lot** easier.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Look into a `For` loop to go through a `Range` of cells. Good starting point.

Comment: @AnnavonBlohn If I right understand, you want to add to selection the cells from A to D columns in the rows where cells in A and B columns are empty?

Comment: @omegastripes I am trying to select all rows that have no blank cells, so all data sets that are complete

Comment: @AnnavonBlohn Please show a screenshot of your data and tell which data range you want to check for blank cells. Otherwise it your information too unspecific to give a definite answer.

Comment: Anna, any reason why you chose to ignore my question?

Comment: @SiddharthRout no of course not. I don't have the data yet but am supposed to "prepare" the code for another person. So the instructions I have are: Program a macro that selects all complete data sets (rows without blanks) and exports those to an existing Sharepoint List. After that the exported row should be deleted in Excel

Comment: when you say rows without blank, which columns are we looking at? A-D? A to Z?

Comment: @SiddharthRout As I don't have Access to the data yet I can't tell. But I thought extending the code for more columns later on wouldn't be a problem. So in the code I have written now I was checking for the columns A-D but I thought I could easily add the "checking" for more columns if needed

Comment: ok one moment... posting an answer

Answer (score 1):

> @SiddharthRout As I don't have Access to the data yet I can't tell. But I thought extending the code for more columns later on wouldn't be a problem. So in the code I have written now I was checking for the columns A-D but I thought I could easily add the "checking" for more columns if needed – Anna von Blohn 43 secs ago

In that case, here is a sample code.

**Logic**

1. As @Pᴇʜ mentioned avoid the use of `.Select`. Work with the objects.
2. Find the last row and loop through the rows. To find the last you you may want to see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)
3. One way (which I am using) is to count the number of cells which are filled using `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA`. So if it is columns `A` to `D` then there should be 4 cells to be filled to consider the "row" as filled. Similarly for Cols A to E, there should be 5 cells to be filled to consider the "row" as filled as so on.

**Code**

I have commented the code. So if you have a problem understanding it, let me know.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectRowsWithNoBlanks()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim myRange As Range, rng As Range
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row in Col A
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Loop through the rows
        For i = 2 To lRow
            '~~> Change this as applicable
            Set rng = .Range("A" & i & ":D" & i)
            
            '~~> Check if the range is completely filled
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = rng.Columns.Count Then
                '~~> Store the range in a range object
                If myRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set myRange = rng
                Else
                    Set myRange = Union(myRange, rng)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    'If Not myRange Is Nothing Then Debug.Print myRange.Address
    
    '~~> Check if any filled rows were found
    If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
        With myRange
            '
            '~~> Do what you want with the range
            '
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No filled rows were found"
    End If
End Sub
```